# Deploying rails application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi do anyone of you know how to deploy Rails Application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk? Previously i had 2 PHP application runs on AWS which is easy to deploy. Also is there any specific EC2 server we need to choose in order to deploy rails application, how would we automate rails server command? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no Ruby on Rails Elastic Beanstalk at this time. You could do a JRuby setup where you compile your app into a WAR file and deploy on the Java Elastic Beanstalk. See the following link for a tutorial http://techylinguist.com/posts/2012/01/13/deploy-jruby-rails-application-war/

But personally I wouldn't recommend it. For deploying Rails apps on AWS I use Opscode Chef. They have some tutorials on their site at http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Guides

**UPDATE:**

AWS Elastic Beanstalk now supports Ruby on Rails. See their documentation http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Thanks fren, very useful article

Comment: No need any longer, Elastic Beanstalk now supports Ruby!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is long after the original question was asked, but AWS Elastic Beanstalk now supports Ruby (1.8 and 1.9).  You can [view the announcement here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/11/aws-elastic-beanstalk-ruby-support-and-vpc-integration.html).